# Clicking a button doesn't work before unfocusing textarea

Tags: html, css, button, textarea

I have a html textarea set to expand on focus, and right below that i have button for submitting whatever the users put into the textarea. When the textarea is expanded clicking the button does not fire the onclick event but instead it just puts the textarea out of focus causing it to get smaller Again. How can i make the onclick event fire on the first click?
The html looks  like this:

```
<div id="commentSection">
<div id="commentsContainer">
</div>
<div id="inputContainer">
    <textarea placeholder="add a comment" id="txtTitle"></textarea>
</div>
<div>   
    <button onclick="return addListItem()">Post</button>
</div>
```

The button doesn't have any styles attached but the textarea has the following:

```
#txtTitle {
width: 878px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
height: 30px;
transition: height 0.2s;
}

#txtTitle:focus {
height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hack using `required` property to determine when the input has some value inside it.

```js
function addListItem(){
  console.log('inside addListItem');
}
```

```css
#txtTitle {
    width: 878px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    height: 30px;
    transition: height 0.2s;
}

#txtTitle:valid {  
    height: 100px;
}
#txtTitle:focus {  
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="commentSection">
<div id="commentsContainer">
</div>
<div id="inputContainer">
    <textarea placeholder="add a comment" id="txtTitle" required></textarea>
</div>
<div>   
    <button onclick="return addListItem()">Post</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Wasn't aware of that pseudo class but this was exactly what i was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Sure. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when your textarea height moves so does the button. With a transitions of 0.2s by the time you've clicked where the button was originally the textarea has resized and moved the button away from where you originally clicked.

One way around this would to add some javascript to check if the input has a value, if it has a value then keep it the same height - if it's empty then resize it ( this is purely based on the idea that the text area requires a value to be submitted)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I suppose this would Work but i went with Kaushiks suggestion to avoid adding more js.